# unwanted line with link between divs

Tags: html, css

I'm using html and css to make 3 boxes act as links, equally spaced apart. For some reason when I got the divs to be equally spaced, a line was created between all three, acting as a link to the div left of the line.

Why is the line there?

here is the code: (with some stuff taken out)

```css
.divider{
 text-align: center;
}
.image{
 float:left;
}
#javatut, #frgames, #scratchtut{
 display: inline-block;
 zoom: 2.0;
 background-color: #c0c0c0;
 text-align: center;
 padding: 10px;
 width: 20%;
}
#javatut {
 border: 2px solid #ff8300;
}
#frgames {
 border: 2px solid #0000ff;
}
#scratchtut {
 border: 2px solid #ff8300;
}
#container {
    text-align: justify;
}
.stretch {
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
 <a href="url">
  <div id="javatut">
   <!-- stuff in here -->
  </div>
 </a>
 <a href="url">
  <div id="frgames">
   <!-- stuff in here -->
  </div>
 </a>
 <a href="url">
  <div id="scratchtut">
   <!-- stuff in here -->
  </div>
 </a>
 <span class="stretch"></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line is caused by the browsers default styling of links as underlined. Just set `text-decoration: none;` on your links and the line will be invisible.

```css
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
.divider {
  text-align: center;
}
.image {
  float: left;
}
#javatut,
#frgames,
#scratchtut {
  display: inline-block;
  zoom: 2.0;
  background-color: #c0c0c0;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 20%;
}
#javatut {
  border: 2px solid #ff8300;
}
#frgames {
  border: 2px solid #0000ff;
}
#scratchtut {
  border: 2px solid #ff8300;
}
#container {
  text-align: justify;
}
.stretch {
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <a href="url">
    <div id="javatut">
      <!-- stuff in here -->
    </div>
  </a>
  <a href="url">
    <div id="frgames">
      <!-- stuff in here -->
    </div>
  </a>
  <a href="url">
    <div id="scratchtut">
      <!-- stuff in here -->
    </div>
  </a>
  <span class="stretch"></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because `text-decoration` CSS property. Set to none, and it works.

`#container a {
    text-decoration: none;
}`

Answer (score -1):

Your markup is not right

Make your a tags inside the div, all your styles will work correctly

check this

```css
.divider {
  text-align: center;
}
.image {
  float: left;
}
#javatut,
#frgames,
#scratchtut {
  display: inline-block;
  zoom: 2.0;
  background-color: #c0c0c0;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 20%;
}
#javatut {
  border: 2px solid #ff8300;
}
#frgames {
  border: 2px solid #0000ff;
}
#scratchtut {
  border: 2px solid #ff8300;
}
#container {
  text-align: justify;
}
.stretch {
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">

  <div id="javatut">

    <a href="url">
    </a>
  </div>


  <div id="frgames">
    <!-- stuff in here -->
    <a href="url">
    </a>
  </div>
  <div id="scratchtut">
    <!-- stuff in here -->

    <a href="url"></a>
  </div>

  <span class="stretch"></span>
</div>
```

Hope this helps
You can also do using flexbox for this

Comment: Actually OP is placing content inside the div which is wrapped with the a tag..i think the behavior he needs is to click on the content of the div